# Modify character in string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple program to decode a simple shift cipher.
Text is shifted a number of characters. So 'c' in the coded text = 'a' in the decoded text. An offset of 2. etc
So, read a character or a string from a text file, then subtract the offset from that character, and put into a new 'decoded' string.
Easy in C - pulling my hair out in Python!
Can someone please point me in the right direction?
The simpler the code the better - I'm no Python expert.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried until now? Any piece of code?

Comment: To do arithmetics on characters, use `ord` and `chr`: `chr(ord('a') + 1) == 'b'`

Comment: This is a Caesar Cipher.  Python [Encode/Decode algorithm & code](https://inventwithpython.com/chapter14.html)

Comment: Thanks for this guys..... ord was what was missing from my vocab. I was trying int - and of course it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
# for decoding
def decode(string, base=2):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(a)+2) for a in string])

# for encoding
def encode(string, base=2):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(a)-2) for a in string])
```

if you want to read from file

```
text = open("filename.txt", "r").read()

print(encode(text))
```

But, you must know that if you encode('a'), the return value will be '_', if you want just an alphabet try this

```
#for decode
def decode_a(string, base=2):
    a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    return ''.join(a[(base+a.index(i)) % len(a)] for i in string)

#for encode
def encode_a(string, base=2):
    a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    return ''.join(a[(a.index(i)-base) % len(a)] for i in string)
```

if you want to read from input

```
e = encode_a(input())

# return e because you decoded again
print(decode_a(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to go from a char to an int using ord(), make the shift with the int, and to go back from an int to a char using chr().

```
coded = 'jgnnq'
decoded = ''.join(chr(ord(c)-2) for c in coded)  # decoded is now 'hello'
```

Comment: Hello @jpaul, [did you go through how to write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This should help you avoid being downvoted.